# wso2 EI 7.1.0 Illegal character: <t>

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

hello i am working on wso2 EI 7.1.0 i created a proxy that work with mqtt transport i want to save the data to a mongodb database but u got the error Illegal character:  (json payload malformed) the data appears on mongodb

here is my proxy service

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="mongoproxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="mqtt" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    
    <target>
        <inSequence>
        <property name="Content-Encoding" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
            <mongodb.insertOne configKey="connectionURI">
                <collection>TestDatabase</collection>
                <document>{json-eval($)}</document>
            </mongodb.insertOne>
            <property name="Content-Encoding" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="mqtt.connection.factory">mqttConFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.content.type">application/json</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.subscription.qos">2</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.topic.name">esb.test1</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.session.clean">false</parameter>
</proxy>
```

and here is my error :

> ```
> [2021-04-01 12:45:26,249] ERROR {OMSourcedElementImpl} - Could not get parser from data source for element jsonObject
> ```
>
> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Illegal
> character: 
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:88)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:170)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:462)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonDataSource.getReader(JsonDataSource.java:154)
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:224)
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:253)
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getChildren(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:862)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:640)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:648)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeChildrenFromPayloadBody(JsonUtil.java:906)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:885)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:1006)
> at org.wso2.carbon.connector.utils.MongoUtils.setPayload(MongoUtils.java:95)
> at org.wso2.carbon.connector.operations.InsertOne.connect(InsertOne.java:79)
> at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:94)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:134)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:169)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:92)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:226)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.mqtt.MqttListenerCallback.messageArrived(MqttListenerCallback.java:54)
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:475)
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:379)
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:183)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Illegal character: 
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.yylex(JsonScanner.java:777)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.nextSymbol(JsonScanner.java:310)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:136)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:272)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:151)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:243)
> ... 31 more
>
> ```
> [2021-04-01 12:45:26,252] ERROR {MongoUtils} - Error occurred while inserting the document to the database
> ```
>
> org.apache.synapse.commons.SynapseCommonsException: Existing json
> payload is malformed. MessageID :
> urn:uuid:1088D53BFF2A85D11E1617273916741
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeChildrenFromPayloadBody(JsonUtil.java:911)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:885)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:1006)
> at org.wso2.carbon.connector.utils.MongoUtils.setPayload(MongoUtils.java:95)
> at org.wso2.carbon.connector.operations.InsertOne.connect(InsertOne.java:79)
> at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:94)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:134)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:169)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:92)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:226)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.mqtt.MqttListenerCallback.messageArrived(MqttListenerCallback.java:54)
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:475)
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:379)
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:183)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error obtaining parser from data source:java.io.IOException: Illegal character: 
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:230)
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:253)
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getChildren(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:862)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:640)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:648)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeChildrenFromPayloadBody(JsonUtil.java:906)
> ... 21 more
> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Illegal character: 
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:88)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:170)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:462)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonDataSource.getReader(JsonDataSource.java:154)
> at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:224)
> ... 26 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Illegal character: 
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.yylex(JsonScanner.java:777)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.nextSymbol(JsonScanner.java:310)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:136)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:272)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:151)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:243)
> ... 31 more